# Alternative functional style written in rust

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, rust

How to correct the syntax error in the section 2? An error message was shown

```
error[E0277] slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
```

when the section 2 was compiled. (Section 1 and section 2; both are same functionality in different programming styles.)

```
extern crate rand;

use std::iter;
use rand::Rng;

fn estimateAreaCircleMonteCarlo() {
    let box_area = 4.0;
    let numIteration = 100000;

    let mut x = Vec::<f64>::with_capacity(numIteration);
    let mut y = Vec::<f64>::with_capacity(numIteration);
    let mut distance = Vec::<f64>::with_capacity(numIteration);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    x = iter::repeat(())
        .map(|()| rng.gen_range(-1., 1.))
        .take(numIteration)
        .collect::<Vec<f64>>();

    y = iter::repeat(())
        .map(|()| rng.gen_range(-1., 1.))
        .take(numIteration)
        .collect::<Vec<f64>>();

    // section 1, it is able to be compiled.
    distance = (0..numIteration)
        .map(|i| (x[i].powi(2) + y[i].powi(2)).sqrt())
        .collect::<Vec<f64>>();

    // section 2, same functionality as section 1 but it cannot be compiled.
    // error[E0277]^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
    /*
    distance = iter::repeat(())
        .map(|i| (x[i].powi(2) + y[i].powi(2)).sqrt())
        .take(numIteration)
        .collect::<Vec<f64>>();
    */

    println!("x={}", x[numIteration - 1]);
    println!("y={}", y[numIteration - 1]);
    println!("distance={}", distance[numIteration - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`iter::repeat(())` creates an iterator that yields `()` (the unit type). Then you map those iterated items with this closure:

```
|i| (x[i].powi(2) + y[i].powi(2)).sqrt()
```

`i` is thus of type `()`. You cannot index something with `()` as said by the compiler:

```
the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[f64]>` is not implemented for `()`
```

One way to solve this could be to enumerate:

```
distance = iter::repeat(()).enumerate()
    .map(|(i, _)| (x[i].powi(2) + y[i].powi(2)).sqrt())
    .take(numIteration)
    .collect();
```

But your first solution is better because the `iter::repeat` stuff is useless.

---

Note that you make some unnecessary allocations if you do not need to keep the `x`s and `y`s. This code can be simply written as:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn estimate_area_circle_monteCarlo() {
    let num_iteration = 100000;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let distances: Vec<_> = (0..num_iteration)
        .map(|_| {
            let x: f32 = rng.gen_range(-1., 1.);
            let y: f32 = rng.gen_range(-1., 1.);
            (x.powi(2) + y.powi(2)).sqrt()
        })
        .collect();

    println!("last distance = {}", distances.last().unwrap());
}
```

Use `collect` only if you actually want a `Vec`, an `HashSet` or whatever. If your purpose is to iterate over some data, keep the iterator as is.

Comment: thank you for your help. An error message was shown "_^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found struct `std::iter::Map". compile successfully with the following modification "distance = iter::repeat(())
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, _)| (x[i].powi(2) + y[i].powi(2)).sqrt())
        .take(numIteration)
        .collect::<Vec<f64>>();"

Comment: @madeinQuant I didn't write the full code... only the problematic part.

Comment: @madeinQuant I did write the `collect` as well, if you want.

Answer (score -1):

There is a final version for reference.

```
distance = iter::repeat(())
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, _)| (x[i].powi(2) + y[i].powi(2)).sqrt())
        .take(numIteration)
        .collect::<Vec<f64>>();
```